# Seeing if a file exists and printing it

Tags: python, io

So I'm trying to create a method that can search files and print them out.

```
def search():
    searched = input("... ")
    with open(searched + ".py", "r") as my_file:
        print(my_file)
search()
```

but the console prints out <_io.TextIOWrapper name='RandomPrac.py' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
What does this mean?

Comment: You printed the file object instead of the contents. Try `print(my_file.read())`

Comment: This is file handler object, maybe you need `my_file.read()` to read file data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you print `my_file` variable, which is of type `_io.TextIOWrapper`. What you actually need is

```
print(my_file.read())
```

Answer (score 3):

As [Ali Yilmaz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50320544/908494) already nicely explains, you're printing the file object, not the contents of that file.

For smallish files, just `read()` the file to get the contents as a string, and print that, as in his answer. And, since you're searching for `*.py` files, you almost certainly do have smallish files.

But if the file might be gigantic, it's probably better to loop over it and print each line as you read it:

```
for line in my_file:
    print(line, end='')
```

Or, if you want to be more concise but possibly too clever:

```
print(*my_file, sep='')
```